# Fold out a numpy array along a new dimension using values as index

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `[m,m]` numpy array with element in `{0, 1, 2, ..., 24}`, now I want separate each number in a third dimension to get a `[m,m,24]` array.

a simple example, `[5,5]` array with element in `{0, 1, 2, 3}`

```
[0 0 1 0 0
 2 0 3 0 1
 0 2 3 1 0
 0 0 1 0 0
 1 0 2 0 1]
```

Now I need get a `[5,5,3]` array

```
[[0 0 1 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1
  0 0 0 1 0
  0 0 1 0 0
  1 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0
  2 0 0 0 0
  0 2 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 2 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 3 0 0
  0 0 3 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Currently I have a simple method, but it's very computational expensive. Because I need to do this operation frequently.

```
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=2)
for i in range(24):
    img_norm[..., i] = (img[..., 0] == (i + np.ones(shape=img[..., 0].shape)))
```

For `64` array with size `[224,224]` and element in `{0, 1, 2, ..., 24}`, The code above takes about `5s`.

Is there a faster way to do it?

Comment: What happened to the `0`s in your example? You only seem to match for 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Can you provide us a way to test a large dataset ? Thanks

Comment: Not sure why this question is getting downvotes. It's just fine. Want a test dataset? Make one in a one-liner! See answers so far for inspiration.

Comment: @9769953 OP doesn't care about the zeros.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I don't see that stated in the question: it explicitly mentions elements `{0, 1, 2, 3}` in the example, and similar for the actual data. It'd be good if the OP clarifies that.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late. Here is a [sample data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/apr2a9ost04irhs/dat.png?dl=0). It's a 224x224 image of a human segmentation of 24 part. I need to separate each part into a individual channel during training. So I need a fast way to perform this operation.

Comment: @9769953 It is apparent from the given example that the zeros aren't meant to get registered in the output 3D array. (Because, if they were, it would just be a full 2D layer of zeros – no value in that – trivial to add if it is desired.)

Comment: For 224x224 arrays, what you ask is still fine. However, if your arrays get larger, then it's probably going to be more efficient to parse each layer one at a time, rather than combining them all into a single array. (E.g. you probably do not feel like operating on a single 2000x2000x200 array, and would much prefer to operate on 20 single 2000x2000 arrays separately, so you don't have to keep them all in memory.)

Comment: @acdr Hi, my data size is `[64, 224, 224, 1]` with elements all in the set of `{0, 1, 2, ..., 24}`, and I need to convert them to `[64, 224, 224, 24]` before feeding into the network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is pretty speedy for me:

```
import numpy as np
max_num = 3
img = np.array([
    [0,0,1,0,0],
    [2,0,3,0,1],
    [0,2,3,1,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0],
    [1,0,2,0,1],
    ])

img_norm = np.zeros(img.shape + (max_num,))
for idx in range(1, max_num + 1):
    img_norm[idx-1,:,:]=idx*(img == idx)
```

Testing it with a random array of your specified size;

```
max_num = 24
img = np.int64((max_num+1)*np.random.rand(224, 224)) # Random array

img_norm = np.zeros(img.shape + (max_num,))
for idx in range(1, max_num + 1):
    img_norm[idx-1,:,:]=img*(img == idx)
```

Hardly takes any time at all on my machine.

```
def getnorm_acdr(img):
    max_num = np.max(img)
    img_norm = np.zeros([max_num, *img.shape])    
    for idx in range(1, max_num + 1):
        img_norm[idx-1,:,:]=img*(img == idx)

img = np.int64((max_num+1)*np.random.rand(224, 224))

%timeit getnorm_acdr(img)
```

Gives:

```
11.9 ms ± 536 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely more elegant: use `np.ndenumerate()`.

```
for (i,j), val in np.ndenumerate(img):
    img_norm[val-1,i,j] = val
```

Looks like this should be faster than yours because O(N^2) rather than O(N^3). Let's try it out on an array with size and content as you describe:

```
def getnorm_ndenumerate(img):
    img_norm = np.zeros([np.max(img), *img.shape])
    for (i,j), val in np.ndenumerate(img):
        img_norm[val-1,i,j] = val  
    return img_norm

b = np.int64(25*np.random.rand(224, 224)) 

%timeit getnorm_ndenumerate(b)
```

gives

```
47.8 ms ± 1.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

It is indeed faster than yours. But the elegance comes at a price, because it is slower than [acdr's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126366/119775).

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake, in the output array, all the non-zeros should be 1. Sorry for my silly mistake.

thanks for all your help. I tested the three methods above, including code from `Jean-François Corbett`, `acdr` + `Jean-François Corbett` and mine.
It turns out the method from `acdr` + `Jean-François Corbett` is the fastest.

Here is my testing code

```
def test_time():
    def func1(img, max_num):
        w, h = img.shape
        img_norm = np.zeros([w, h, max_num], np.float32)
        for (i, j), val in np.ndenumerate(img):
            # img_norm[i, j, val - 1] = val
            img_norm[i, j, val - 1] = 0 if val == 0 else 1
        return img_norm

    def func2(img, max_num):
        w, h = img.shape
        img_norm = np.zeros([w, h, max_num], np.float32)
        for idx in range(1, max_num + 1):
            # img_norm[:, :, idx - 1] = idx*(img == idx)
            img_norm[:, :, idx - 1] = (img == idx)
        return img_norm

    def func3(img, max_num):
        w, h = img.shape
        img_norm = np.zeros([w, h, max_num], np.float32)
        for idx in range(max_num):
            # img_norm[:, :, idx] = (idx+1) * (img[:, :, 0] == (idx + np.ones(shape=img[:, :, 0].shape)))
            img_norm[:, :, idx] = (img == (idx + np.ones(shape=img.shape)))
        return img_norm

    import cv2
    img_tmp = cv2.imread('dat.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    img_tmp = np.asarray(img_tmp, np.int)

    # img_tmp = np.array([
    #     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    #     [2, 0, 3, 0, 1],
    #     [0, 2, 3, 1, 0],
    #     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    #     [1, 0, 2, 0, 1],
    # ])

    img_bkp = np.array(img_tmp, copy=True)
    print(img_bkp.shape)
    import time
    cnt = 100
    maxnum = 24
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(cnt):
        _ = func1(img_tmp, maxnum)
    print('1 total time =', time.time() - start_time)

    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(cnt):
        _ = func2(img_tmp, maxnum)
    print('2 total time =', time.time() - start_time)

    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(cnt):
        _ = func3(img_tmp, maxnum)
    print('3 total time =', time.time() - start_time)

    print((img_tmp == img_bkp).all())
    img1 = func1(img_tmp, maxnum)
    img2 = func2(img_tmp, maxnum)
    img3 = func3(img_tmp, maxnum)
    print(img1.shape, img2.shape, img3.shape)
    print((img1 == img2).all())
    print((img2 == img3).all())
    print((img1 == img3).all())
    # print(type(img1[0, 0, 0]), type(img2[0, 0, 0]), type(img3[0, 0, 0]))
    # print('img1\n', img1[:, :, 2])
    # print('img3\n', img3[:, :, 2])
```

The output is

```
    (224, 224)
    1 total time = 4.738261938095093
    2 total time = 0.7725710868835449
    3 total time = 1.5980615615844727
    True
    (224, 224, 24) (224, 224, 24) (224, 224, 24)
    True
    True
    True
```

If there is any problem, please post it in comments.

Thanks for all your kind help!